# Using CASE or NVL

Tags: sql, oracle10g

i would like to change code below by using SUM(NVL). any suggestion.

```
sum(CASE WHEN D.CURRENCY ='MYR' OR D.CURRENCY IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Cur
```

previously i create this, but i cannot sum the 'CURRENCY' column which is 'MYR'. this column have null value.

```
 NVL(D.CURRENCY,'MYR') CUR4
```

the red one i bold must display 'MYR'

[image]

Comment: `case` is just fine!

Comment: try to make use of DECODE

Comment: @jarlh i need use nvl my senior suggest me to use that but ididnt know how to do it

Comment: "but i cannot sum the 'CURRENCY' column which is 'MYR' . this column...." - could you please explain these sentences a bit in detail?

Comment: i need to sum total 'BUY' for currency 'MYR'. some data for currency is NULL. so cannot . i print screen the oracle report to give clear what problem i have.

Comment: @KaushikNayak already update the question. Because the original one it will be 4 rows contain BUY with MYR, BUY with NULL, SELL with MYR and SELL with NULL. so i try use case to combined. but cannot display CURRENCY IN 'MYR'. like the pic I upload above.

Answer (score 0):

First you have `sum()` function which actually counting the no of `MYR` in `CURRENCY` column rather than  doing the `sum`

So, you just filter the `NULL`s by either `COALESCE()` or `NVL()`

```
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(D.CURRENCY,'MYR') = 'MYR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CUR4
```

Comment: i'm already get his one. Actually i still want to display 'MYR' for that column. after sum it.